# Display order of checked checkboxes next to each checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have list of many checkboxes and I need to display the order of them being checked next to each other.
Something like this:

```
[1] checkbox
    checkbox
    checkbox
[2] checkbox
    checkbox
[3] checkbox
```

Order in which they are being checked does not matter, the thing is that they need to be ordered from top to bottom as showed.

I have limited options with editing the HTML, since it is dinamically rendered, and the structure looks like this:

```
<td>
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      "Sample text"
   </label>
</td>
<td>
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      "Sample text"
   </label>
</td>
<td>
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      "Sample text"
   </label>
</td>
etc.
```

So I have tried the following:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
    var number = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
    $('label:has(input[type=checkbox]:checked)').text(number);
});
```

But it ends up replacing each `label` contents with 1 (not even a count).

I searched for answers here on Stackoverflow and I found the most suitable as this one:

```
document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(el => {
  el.innerHTML += '<span class="letter"> </span>'
})
let checkedItems=[]
document.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]').forEach(el => {
el.value = el.closest('label').innerText.trim()
  el.addEventListener('change', e => {
    let n = el.closest('label').innerText.trim();
    if (!e.target.checked)  checkedItems.splice(checkedItems.indexOf(n),1)
    else checkedItems.push(n);
    document.querySelectorAll('.letter').forEach( l=> l.innerHTML = '')
    checkedItems.forEach((n,i) => {
    document.querySelector(`input[value=${n}]`).closest('td').querySelector('.letter').innerHTML = i;
    })
 
  });

});
```

In this case I get an error caused by the input value, since it is not alphanumeric. In what way can I edit either of these in order to work? Thank you!

EDIT: I have found the problem in the last code block in my question > it was in the `input[value=${n}]`, since it did not match my input values, I just did not spend that much time in dev tools to see this before asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly that you wish to display, next to the checkbox itself, the order ( out of all checkboxes ) that a particular checkbox was checked then perhaps the following might work?

`querySelectorAll` can be combined with the `:checked` attribute selector to find the number of checked elements and this is then used within a new `span` element which is appeneded to the `label` element when the delegated event listener fires a `changed` event.

**update**
per the comment by @janPfiefer, a resequencing function could be added if required to re-index the checked order should all checkboxes be checked and then some unchecked in random sequence.

```js
const resequence=()=>{
  let col=document.querySelectorAll('table [type="checkbox"]:checked');
      col.forEach(n=>{
        let span=n.parentNode.querySelector('span');
            span.textContent=Math.max( 1, parseInt( span.textContent ) - 1 );
      })
};

document.addEventListener('change',e=>{
  if( e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement && e.target.type=='checkbox' ){
    let index=document.querySelectorAll('table [type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    let label=e.target.parentNode;
    
    if( e.target.checked ){
      let span=document.createElement('span');
          span.textContent=index;
      label.appendChild( span )
    }else{
      label.removeChild( label.querySelector('span') );
      resequence();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      "Sample text"
   </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      "Sample text"
   </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      "Sample text"
   </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have found the typo in my code, the problem was that I was missing " " around input value, so thats why it was not accepting it. Your solution does the trick as well.

Comment: What about situation when you check all checkboxes and then uncheck nr.1? Checkboxes order will remain 2 and 3.

Comment: @JanPfeifer - that is true - would be simple enough to add another routine in to resequence if that was required.

Answer (score 1):

#### Introduction and assumptions:

I edited the html putting the `<input>` before the `<label>` and no more nested inside it as before. I did it because the label should not contain the input element and should be a distinct element and also because I needed an after element to style following the checkbox. It could be a wrong assumption if you needed the html to remain exactly the same. Anyway there's a further attempt later that will also address the original html.

So we have this:

```
<td>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>Sample text</label>
</td>
```

Instead of this:

```
<td>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    "Sample text"
  </label>
</td>
```

#### Showing table columns as rows instead:

You may simply have a css rule addressing the `<tr>` elements and turn them as flex container with a column direction:

```
tr{
  display: flex;  
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

#### Using CSS counters:

It could be worth knowing that you could achieve the same result you are chasing with js, but using css only with css rulesets like these:

```
body{
  counter-reset: checked-cb;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
  counter-increment: checked-cb;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after{
  content: " " counter(checked-cb);
}
```

Where a counter `checked-cb` is incremented at each input checked and echoed in an `::after` pseudo element inside the label following.

#### Using the same css approach with the original html:

Since `<input>` elements are self contained they cannot host `::after` elements so we are forced to style its parent because there are no other sibling elements to adopt as container like we had in the example before where I made the html a little better.

Unfortunately the only css selector to get there requires the `:has()` psudo class ***currently still not supported on Firefox***:

```
*:has(> input[type="checkbox"]:checked)::after{ 
  content: counter(checked-cb);
}
```

#### References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters

> CSS counters let you adjust the appearance of content based on its
> location in a document. For example, you can use counters to
> automatically number the headings in a webpage, or to change the
> numbering on ordered lists.
>
> Counters are, in essence, variables maintained by CSS whose values may
> be incremented or decremented by CSS rules that track how many times
> they're used. You can define your own named counters, and you can also
> manipulate the list-item counter that is created by default for all
> ordered lists.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

> The functional :has() CSS pseudo-class represents an element if any of
> the relative selectors that are passed as an argument match at least
> one element when anchored against this element. This pseudo-class
> presents a way of selecting a parent element or a previous sibling
> element with respect to a reference element by taking a relative
> selector list as an argument.

#### Demo (w/ html improved):

```css
body {
  counter-reset: checked-cb;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  counter-increment: checked-cb;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+*::after {
  content: " " counter(checked-cb);
}

tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<table class="showasrows">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label>Sample text</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label>Sample text</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label>Sample text</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, I have actually learned a lot from your answer, things I did not know were possible with pure CSS!

Answer (score 0):

Add span as a container for a number:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="nr"></span>Text X
</label>
```

Then script will be:

```
const cbs = $("input[type=checkbox]");
      cbs.click(function() {
          let order = 0;

          cbs.each(function(i,o) {
              const nr = $(o).next();
              if(o.checked) {
                  order++;
                  nr.html(order);
              } else {
                  nr.html("");
              }
          });
        });
```

Comment: That would do the trick as well, but the problem here is that I have no way of effecting the layout of HTML here. The form is rendered through PHP framework. The problem is already solved, thank you for your time.